# This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I'm trying to flag this question ([Status bar rendering warning in Xcode 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855843/status-bar-rendering-warning-in-xcode-9-3)) as duplicate of this ([Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586341/status-bar-could-not-find-cached-time-string-image-rendering-in-process?rq=1)). But I'm not allowed to do so, with following error:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

[image]

Isn't it duplicate question?

Comment: The primary purpose of duplicates is to point the asker and others with the same problem to the "best" solution to the problem.  Given that the original question is considered unanswered since it doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer, closing it as a duplicate doesn't achieve that primary goal, so the system prevents you from voting to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: The exception is when that other question is from the same asker, right? (This to be able to close someone *literally* duplicating his own questions "because i received no good answr".)

Comment: IMO the attempted answers on the question you're trying to close are better than the one on the dupe link target. If dupe closing becomes possible at some point in time, do consider doing it the other way around.

Comment: This reminds me, by the way of a thought I've had before. (I may be the only one.) Why do these not-possibly-to-mark-duplicates appear in the list of "suggested duplicates"? The same school of thinking that lead to "Click Here to upvote this answer  ⇝ You cannot upvote your own answer"?

Comment: Something that you can do to "get around this" is to leave a comment and say something along the lines of "This question may help you out. <LINK>" or something to that effect.

Comment: @psubsee2003 "Given that the original question is considered unanswered since it doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer, closing it as a duplicate doesn't achieve that primary goal" Not necessarily. Often there are questions which are answered in the comments (e.g. "hey this looks like a bug / ok i've filed a bug / this new version just fixes your bug report"), just nobody added that as an answer.

Comment: comments aren't answers.  It would be up to someone to take the comment and expand it to a real answer.